# No onkeypress event fired on pressing cmd+z/y in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, uiwebview, safari, ios8

I have a HTML5 based web app which contains a text editor. I have handled undo/redo actions inside js code. But when i use my app inside UIWebview i am not able to handle undo/redo events because of undoManager of UIWebView. No "onkeypress" event is fired on the document. Also same issue when i use predictive text suggestions feature of iOS 8. No keypress event is fired.

Any suggestions??

Comment: No, filed a bug with apple with sample. Response still awaited.